# Failed to start MDS cs

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

When I attempt to run my blackberry app in the simulator I get the following error **"Failed to start MDS CS. Reason:".** The error message is not very helpful since it does not give a reason its just blank. I was wondering if anyone else has seen this error?

**My Setup is**
Windows 7,
Eclipse with Webworks plugin

**Error Occurs** when I attempt to start MDS Connection Service in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this was caused by installing the java SDK in the wrong folder. I installed it in the program files x86 (64 Bit) folder. I reinstalled to the program files (32 Bit) folder and update the environment variables and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. In my case, I needed to start Eclipse as administrator; apparently the scripts want to create a log file under the Program Files directory somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and after fiddling with the path / java_home / java install (eventually sent to c:\java), I was getting a "no logservice loaded" error.

(by the way, the 'run.bat' file has a line that has this code:

```
start cmd /v:on /c "java.exe"
```

remove the 'start' and the window will stop disappearing on an error.)

I had also installed the JDE 7 from RIM and the MDS installed there worked fine.
So I renamed the MDS folder under the Eclipse plugin and copied the MDS folder from under the JDE into the plugin folder.  It now works fine.  Sometimes I have to close the simulator manually, however.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that.

the problem, for me, was that mds work with JDK 1.5 and off course, i had the JDK 6 installed.

i had to install JDK 1.5 and do this:

- put the path enviroment variable to JDK5  and execute mds
- put the path enviroment normal and execute eclipse.